# null date in search query

Tags: oracle

this is a easy question but I can't think of how to do this at the moment.

I have a date field in search query. The query isn't dynamic or this would be easier. I need to be able to return the records that match the date entered or if the date isn't entered then it should return all.

This is what I have but it isn't working. It's not returning any rows, when there is criteria or when there isn't.

```
AND ( (table.dateField = p_dateField) 
   OR (table.dateField = table.dateField and table.dateField is null))
```

thanks in advance.

After an hour of working with it I came up with this:

```
and (  
      ( p_dateField IS NOT NULL AND table.dateField = p_dateField)
         OR ( p_dateField IS NULL AND (table.dateField is null or (table.dateField is not null))
     )
```

It works for the few tests I've been able to run against it. If anyone can suggest a better method please do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried:

`AND ( (table.dateField = p_dateField AND NOT(p_dateField is NULL))
OR p_dateField is NULL)`

I am assuming that p_dateField is the Date parameter

Comment: Hi Simen, I tried that. It returns the record I'm looking for but it also gives me the records where the date is null. I want it to return only the rows that match the date, or if the p_dateField is null, then I want it to return everything.

Comment: Good point: I assumed that the table.dateField didn't allow NULLs. I have updated the left side of the OR statement in my answer to eliminate the null matches from this part of the statement

Answer (score 3):

just write your where condition like this:

```
where previous_conditions
  AND ((table.dateField = p_dateField) or (p_dateField is null))
  and other_conditions;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
AND table.dateField = NVL(pdateField, table.dateField)
```

Assuming table.dateField does not contain nulls. If it does, then perhaps:

```
AND NVL(table.dateField, SYSDATE+10000) = 
        NVL(pdateField, NVL(table.dateField, SYSDATE+10000)
```

Assumes that SYSDATE+10000 is a value not in your data.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using an NVL clause in the OR section:

```
AND ( (table.dateField = p_dateField) 
      OR (NVL(p_datefield, to_date('01/01/1901','MM/DD/YYYY')) =
           to_date('01/01/1901,'MM/DD/YYYY')))
```